# Google Play Game Services and AdMob

Tags: libgdx, admob, google-play-services, google-api-client

I noticed some changes posted on web about Google Play Game Services changing to use GoogleApiClient, and also I read that AdMob should be integrated through Google Play Game Services. I was already using Google Play Game Services with libgdx, but now I want to also integrate AdMob into my game, so I don't know if I should just do the things the old way and integrate them both separately or should I do it somehow else?

Answer (score 0):

The Admob classes are now contained within Google play Services. So if you attempt to add the Admob-6.4.1 lib to your project you will get dex error because of duplicate classes.

You should integrate Admob using the libraries from Google Play Services instead.

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals